# Print integers from a to b with condition

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript. Looking for advice on the approach to this problem:
Given integers a and b, a < b. Print all integers in range [a;b] inclusive, where a is printed 1 time, a+1 2 times...Thanks in advance.
Upd. my approach:

```
"use strict";
console.log("Task 6");
var a = Number(prompt("Enter a"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter b"));
if(a>b){
    var c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
}
for(var i = a; i <= b; i++){
    for(var j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried two nested for loops? The outer loop iterates from `a` to `b` and the inner loop prints the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new function called interger(), then check whether a < b or not, then swap both if its not, using [nested for() loop](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nesting-for-loops-in-javascript/)

```
function interger(a,b){
    if (a>b) {
        let c = b
        b = a
        a = c
    }
    for (; a <= b; a++) {
        for (let index = 0; index < a; index++) {
            console.log(a)
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you want? or did i misunderstanding?
edit : You can do interger(1,5)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: Eg. f(1,5)=1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5

Comment: Ty, in the above is my approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to solve the problem is to start the outer loop with 0 or 1 instead of `a`:

```
"use strict";
console.log("Task 6");
let a = Number(prompt("Enter a"));
let b = Number(prompt("Enter b"));
if(a>b){
    const c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
}
for(let i = 0; i <= b - a; ++i){
    for(let j = 0; j <= i; ++j){
        console.log(i + a);
    }
}
```

Output for `a = 8` and `b = 5`:

```
"Task 6"
5
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
```